Localization of gravitational energy-momentum in plane waves
Dirac ("General Theory of Relativity") shows that in the case of a weak gravitational plane wave, the Einstein pseudo-energy tensor ${t_\mu}^\nu$ has the (approximate) form of a tensor in harmonic coordinates. ("Weak" means the $g_{\mu\nu}$ are approximately constant.) Specifically, if $l_\mu$ is the wave vector, hence $g_{\mu\nu}$ are functions of $l_\sigma x^\sigma$ only, the pseudo-tensor satisfies
$$16π {t_μ}^ν = \frac{1}{2} \left( u_{αβ} u^{αβ} - \frac{1}{2} u^2 \right) l_μ l^ν$$
where $u_{μν}$ is the derivative of $g_{\mu\nu}$ as a function of $l_\sigma x^\sigma$, and $u = u^\mu_\mu$.
Since ${t_μ}^ν$ looks like a tensor, Dirac states that:

"${t_μ}^ν$ transforms like a tensor under those transformations that preserve the character of the field consisting only of waves moving in the direction $l_\sigma$, so that the $g_{\mu\nu}$ remain functions of the single variable $l_\sigma x^\sigma$"

"Such transformations must consist only in the introduction of coordinate waves moving in the direction $l_\sigma$, of the form $x^{\mu'} = x^\mu +b^\mu$ where $b_\mu$ is a function of $l_\sigma x^\sigma$"

"When waves are moving only in one direction, gravitational energy can be localized."


I'm not following this. First, if ${t_μ}^ν$ looks like a tensor in harmonic coordinates, then it behaves like a tensor, period. So the plane-wave character of the field should be evident in all coordinate systems, right? How does Dirac conclude 2. and 3.?
